# How do I make explorer.exe load my desktop quicker once past the login screen?

Tags: windows-10, performance, windows-explorer, windows-10-v21h1

I've finally managed to improve the performance of my laptop using multiple solutions as described in the threads I've made on various windows technical support forums. The line is only going to keep going up.

[image: reliability monitor 24th october 2021 going up]

However I have a minor performance problem. After I enter my password using the login screen, explorer.exe takes a long time to load. It takes a couple of seconds for my icons to appear on my desktop. All I see is the taskbar and the desktop wallpaper but with no icons on it. Eventually the icons begin to load. Once that's done, it takes a couple of seconds for all the pinned program icons and system tray icons to appear on the taskbar.

Is there a way to speed this up? What could be slowing it down?

Pressing the windows key to open the start menu doesn't work as it just causes the screen to go black then explorer.exe crashes to reopen again.

I'm using Windows 10 21H1

Comment: Is Windows installed on an SSD? How about the disc and CPU usage while the desktop is loading. You can use Windows Performance Toolkit (WPA) to collect details info about the startup process.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking at is the reliability monitor which is not an indicator of the overall performance of your computer. It's rather for finding problems with certain apps when they crash.

You can mostly increase the performance of your pc by disabling any autostart applications which you can do under the `Task Manager` -> `Startup`. The more you'll disable there the more performance you should get after this.

Another way is to upgrade your SSD/HDD to an NVME SSD if your mainboard is compatible with that, but that will cost you a bit and require some time for reinstalling everything as a full backup can work, but isn't guaranteed especially if you have a different disk size.